# Java connection to myo

Tags: java, bluetooth, connection, myo

I have a question about the connection from a java application on windows 7 to the myo.

I tried it with the `myo-java` code and I get an error as soon as the connecter has synchronized with the myo. 
The error:

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000686951c2, pid=9124, tid=0x00000000000021ac

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 V  [jvm.dll+0x1451c2]

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 D:\Users\zfatzt\workspace\Mayo\hs_err_pid9124.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Is it possible to deactivate the synchronization or is there even a better way?